# Why can't I echo into a regex-matched output file

Tags: powershell

I have a file that looks like this:

### filename.txt

```
first line
prefix=C:\Users\me\tmp\out_file.txt
second line
python args
```

What I'm trying to do is run the python script and then echo the output into the file `C:\Users\me\tmp\out_file.txt`. Running the script is very easy, but echoing the output is proving difficult. `filename.txt` is in `C:\Users\me\tmp`, so I open a powershell terminal there and execute the following:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Content -Raw | Select-String -Pattern "(?smi)(?:prefix=([^\n]*?))$.*?(python .*?)$" | %{echo "hello" > $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

What this is doing is matching the python script and the output file (note that in general I will be executing this script for every file, hence the pipes). But this results in the error:

```
Out-File: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\me\tmp\out_file.txt'
```

Now, If I copy and paste that exact filename:

```
echo "hello" > 'C:\Users\me\tmp\out_file.txt'
```

The result works perfectly (it also works without the quotes). So my question is, why does this fail in the `ForEach-Object` loop?

In the end, I will call

```
ForEach-Object -Parallel {Invoke-Expression $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value > $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Which (hopefully) will pipe the output into the output file, but if there is a better way of achieving this that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are capturing the CR (Carriage Return) character at the end of the line. If you look at `$_.Matches.Groups[1]` you'll see:

```
Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 19
Length   : 29
Value    : C:\Users\me\tmp\out_file.txt
```

Note the length of 29, but the file path is only 28 characters. If you do:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Content -Raw | Select-String -Pattern "(?smi)(?:prefix=([^\n]*?))$.*?(python .*?)$" | %{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.ToCharArray()|%{">$_<"}}
```

You should see that the last few entries appear as:

```
>e<
>.<
>t<
>x<
>t<
><
```

Indicating that there's an invisible character there. You can fix that by altering your regex just a little:

```
"(?smi)(?:prefix=(.*?))[\r\n]+.*?(python .*?)$"
```